# How to solve loading performance issues when handling multiple KMLs?

Tags: google, maps

I am using over 10 KML in Google Maps. When I increase the number of KMLs they load too late.

I use checkboxes to hide/show KML layers. With up to 5 KML layers, it worked fine. When I increase the size of the KMLs it's not working normally.

When I check "show", it shows but "hide" does not work ...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If you can provide any details or code samples, you will likely get more meaningful answers. The Google Maps Javascript API documentation does not describe any specific limitations around the number of KML file that can be rendered as layers:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers I imagine your issue is either in the way you are loading the KML files, or the size/complexity of the specific KML files. Sean

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to transform your +10 kml-files into one kmz-file?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @iant: inho packing more kml into one does speed up things (e.g. a least time to download via www shrinks)

Comment: when using google maps to load kml vs kmz, kmz is a alot faster

Answer (score 2):

thanks for answer.. This my web address..

login: user
password: resu

[map link](http://nn-gis.com/map/index.php)

.. all unchecked checkboxes are kmls. / checked checkboxes is marker..

The KML => point and pipeline  show/hide fine.  but when checked others kml its showing but not hide ((